# I want mapping the datamodel to a form how to convert the data type?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-2.0

I use slick2 and playframework2.

I want mapping my model to a from

My model is:

```
object Web extends App{
    case class Subject(id: Int, name:String, describe: String, sub_resource:String, addId:Long, recommand:Int, commentsum :Int, commentnumber: Int, userId: Int)
class Subjects(tag: Tag) extends Table[Subject](tag, "Subject") {
  def id=column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name=column[String]("Name")
  def describe=column[String]("describe")
  def sub_resource=column[String]("Resource")
  def keywords=column[String]("Keyword")
  def addID=column[Long]("Address")
  def recommandrate=column[Int]("Recommand")
  def commentsum=column[Int]("Sum_of_rate")
  def commentnumber=column[Int]("Rate_number")
  def userId=column[Int]("owner")
  def uniqueName = index("idx_grp_name", name, unique = true)
  def * = (id, name,sub_resource,keywords, addID, recommandrate, commentsum, commentnumber,userId)<> (Subject.tupled, Subject.unapply)
  def sub_res=foreignKey("sub_res_FK", sub_resource, resource)(_.link)
  def sub_address=foreignKey("sub_add_FK", addID, address)(_.id)
  def sub_user=foreignKey("sub_user_FK", userId, user)(_.id)
}
val subject = TableQuery[Subject]
}
```

I want mapping it to a dataForm:

```
object ShoplistController extends Controller {
val shopForm = Form(
mapping(
  "id" -> number,
  "name" -> nonEmptyText,
  "describe"->nonEmptyText,
  "sub_resource" -> optional(text),

  "addId"->longNumber, 
  "recommand"->number, 
  "commentsum"->number, 
  "commentnumber"-> number,
  "userId"->number

)((Subject.apply _).tupled)(Subject.unapply)
)
}
```

the error is:

```
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to C:\testprojects\slickplay\target\scala-2.10\
classes...
[error] C:\testprojects\slickplay\app\controllers\ShoplistController.scala:23: t
ype mismatch;
[error]  found   : (Int, String, String, String, Long, Int, Int, Int, Int) => mo
dels.Web.Subject
[error]  required: (Int, String, String, Option[String], Long, Int, Int, Int, In
t) => ?
[error]     )(Subject.apply )(Subject.unapply)
[error]               ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

How to write this mapping method? and is there any example for data mapping to Form for slick2 and playframework2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see the `Form` asks you to provide a `Mapping`, so it should be `"id" -> number`, and not a `"id" -> Int`

UPD: your `Subject`'s `sub_resource` is defined as `String`, but your mapping says it is `optional(text)` which means an `Option[String]`.

You should either change your `Subject` model to `case class Subject(id: Int, name:String, describe: String, sub_resource:Option[String]....` or replace your mapping with `"sub_resource" -> text`